# Issues with childrens and parent data element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list like this: 101,102,104

```
<select>
<option value="100" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text1</option>
<option value="101" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text2</option>
<option value="102" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text3</option>
<option value="103" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text4</option>
<option value="104" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text5</option>
</select>


<select>
<option value="100" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text1</option>
<option value="101" data-parent="" data-childrens="101">Text2</option>
<option value="102" data-parent="102" data-childrens="">Text3</option>
<option value="103" data-parent="" data-childrens="">Text4</option>
<option value="104" data-parent="" data-childrens="104">Text5</option>
</select>
```

I want it to be like this, if i select any value and childrens should appear like this:

trying like this

```
var arr = $("#list1").val().split(',');
                            $.each(arr ,function(i,val) {
                                if(val == $("#sc option:selected").val()) {
                                    $("#sc option:selected").attr('data-parent',val);   
                                }
                                if(val.indexOf($("#sc option").val()) != -1) {
                                    $("#sc option").attr('data-childrens',val); 
                                }
                            });
```

the first if is working but the second does not place the numbers properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing `val.indexOf($("#sc option").val())` is it will always get the value of the first `<option>` only and not check any others

---

You could create an attribute selector like:

```
 $("#sc option[value=" + val + "]").attr('data-childrens',val);
```

Or use `filter()`

```
 $("#sc option").filter(function(){
     return this.value === val
 }).attr('data-childrens',val)
```

Comment: trying use your code with this but it always throwing an error on missing argument )
`$.each(arr,function(i,vals) {
        if(vals == $("#sc option:selected").val()) {
         $("#sc option:selected").attr('data-parent',vals); 
        }
        $("#sc option").filter(function() {
         return this.value === vals  
        }).attr('data-childrens',vals);
       }`

i renamed the `val` to `vals`